# MYSQL Insert Statement not working in code but working in phpmyadmin

Tags: php, mysql

So I just wanted to insert a new record to database using by below query:

```
INSERT INTO ratings VALUES(\'\','".$userid."','".$rating."','".$itemid."')
```

I also tried it with parameters but that didn't work either.

This is the query printed to console:

> INSERT INTO ratings VALUES('','13','3.5','5228')"

The Php Code is this:

```
$query = "INSERT INTO ratings VALUES(\'\','".$userid."','".$rating."','".$itemid."')";
echo '<script>console.log("'.$query.'");</script>';
DB::query($query);
```

And the function to execute the query:

```php
public static function query($query, $params = array()) {
    $statement = self::connect()->prepare($query);
    $statement->execute($params);

    if (explode(' ', $query)[0] == 'SELECT') {
        $data = $statement->fetchAll();
        return $data;
    }
}
```

And the Error that i get is following:

```
Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation:
    1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
    corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax
    to use near '\'\','13','4','5228')'
at line 1 in D:\xampp\htdocs\updatedcollector\classes\DB.php:12
```

Comment: This is missing a lot of information. What was the php code? What's the error output?

Comment: Are you getting any errors? Try `error_reporting(E_ALL);` (place that on the top of your PHP script) and check your MySQL error logs. Also, show more code.

Comment: Im only get the Syntax-Error but i checked everything and i cant find any syntax error

Comment: You're in a double-quoted string, so you don't need to escape your single quotes. If you echo your query, you'll probably see the slashes still there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given this function:

```php
public static function query($query, $params = array()) {
    $statement = self::connect()->prepare($query);
    $statement->execute($params);

    if (explode(' ', $query)[0] == 'SELECT') {
        $data = $statement->fetchAll();
        return $data;
    }
}
```

It seems like what you want to do is this:

```php
$query = "INSERT INTO ratings VALUES('', ?, ?, ?)";
DB::query($query, [$userid, $rating, $itemid]);
```

This provides you with protection against [SQL injection attacks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php).

Comment: yes, but i've done it in the other way like hundreds of times already why does it fail so suddenly? but anyway thanks

Comment: Well don't do it the other way. It's unsafe and guaranteed to break.

Comment: Also, if the first column of `ratings` is an auto-increment, that empty string should more properly be a `NULL`.